# How to get the pagenumber of the content of a bookmark in a PDF with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox version 2.0.x. I am trying to search a PDF using bookmarks and when I hit my target I should be able to get the Pagenumber the bookmark is referring to. This is my code to print all bookmarks. I can do an equals search like `searchText.equals(current.getTitle())`

```
public static void printBookmark(PDOutlineNode bookmark, String indentation) throws IOException {
    PDOutlineItem current = bookmark.getFirstChild();
    COSObject targetPageRef = null;
    while (current != null) {
        System.out.println(indentation + current.getTitle());           
        printBookmark(current, indentation + "    ");
        current = current.getNextSibling();
    }
}
```

If the title matches my search text then that is my target bookmark. Anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

```
public static void printBookmark(PDOutlineNode bookmark, String indentation) throws IOException
{
    PDOutlineItem current = bookmark.getFirstChild();
    COSObject targetPageRef = null;
    while (current != null)
    {
        System.out.println(indentation + current.getTitle());       
        PDPageFitWidthDestination destination = (PDPageFitWidthDestination) current.getDestination();
        System.out.println("Page Number " + destination.retrievePageNumber());
        printBookmark(current, indentation + "    ");
        current = current.getNextSibling();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please replace `PDPageFitWidthDestination` with `PDPageDestination` and add an instance check for `current.getDestination()`. There's no guarantee that you're lucky each time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given a PDDocument object and the PDOutlineItem of that document object, another way of finding the index of the page where bookmark points to could be as follows;

```
    public static void printBookmark2(PDDocument document, PDOutlineNode outline) throws IOException {
        PDOutlineItem current = outline.getFirstChild();

        while (current != null)
        {
            //use PDOutlineItem and PDDocument objects to find the page which the bookmark
            //points to
            PDPage currentPage = current.findDestinationPage(document);
            //use the document and the page to find the index of the page
            Integer currentPageIndex = document.getPages().indexOf(currentPage);
            ...
            //Do other operations
        }
    }
```